# Wrong number of total pages in returned Page

Tags: java, spring-boot, jpa, spring-data-jpa

Spring boot starter parent 3.0.6

I have a controller that accepts get params and pageable for searching cards for trading card game:

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping("/api/cards")
@RequiredArgsConstructor
public class CardsController {

    private final BerserkHeroesCardService cardService;

    @GetMapping
    @ResponseBody
    public Page<BerserkCardModel> getCards(CardSearchRequest searchRequest, Pageable pageable) {
        return cardService.getCards(searchRequest, pageable);
    }
}
```

calling `http://.../api/cards?page=1&size=12` I get correct result:

```
... 
"last": false, 
"totalPages": 228, 
"totalElements": 2726, 
"size": 12, 
...
```

calling `http://.../api/cards?page=2&size=12` I got not expected and incorrect result

```
...  
"last": true,  
"totalPages": 2,  
"totalElements": 23,  
"size": 12, 
...
```

calling `http://.../api/cards?page=3&size=12` I got also incorrect result that differ previous

```
...  
"last": true,  
"totalPages": 3,  
"totalElements": 35,  
"size": 12, 
...
```

calling `http://.../api/cards?page=4&size=12` again return correct result

```
...  
"last": false,  
"totalPages": 228,  
"totalElements": 2726,  
"size": 12, 
...
```

My serviece method

```
@Override     
public Page<BerserkCardModel> getCards(CardSearchRequest request, Pageable pageable) {
    Specification<BerserkCard> spec = Specification.where(null); // mocked for debug         
    Page<BerserkCard> all = berserkCardRepo.findAll(spec, pageable); // findAll returned page incorrect  
                                                                     //result for page 2 and 3         
    return all.map(mapper::toModel);     
}
```

I'im trying to find info about similar bugs but nothing found. Other same services works well.

UPD

I experimented with my jpa repository and commented `@EntityGraph` annotation
and page request now return correct result regardless of page number.

```
public interface BerserkCardRepo extends JpaRepository<BerserkCard, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<BerserkCard> {
   @Override
    //@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"elements"})
    Page<BerserkCard> findAll(@Nullable Specification<BerserkCard> spec, Pageable pageable);

}
```

UPD2

also I'm noticed that for 2 and 3 pages hibernate didn't generate count query. For each other page hibernate does it.

UPD3

I added logging sql when entity graph enabled.

service:

```
    @Override
    public Page<BerserkCardModel> getCards(CardSearchRequest request, Pageable pageable) {
        log.info(String.format("Accept pageable. Page %d, size %d", pageable.getPageNumber(), pageable.getPageSize()));
        Specification<BerserkCard> spec = Specification.where(null);
        Page<BerserkCard> all = berserkCardRepo
                .findAll(spec, pageable);
        log.info(String.format("Found %d elements, total pages: %d", all.getTotalElements(), all.getTotalPages()));
        return all
                .map(mapper::toModel);
    }
```

Repo:

```
public interface BerserkCardRepo extends JpaRepository<BerserkCard, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<BerserkCard> {
    @Override
    @EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"elements"})
    Page<BerserkCard> findAll(@Nullable Specification<BerserkCard> spec, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Entity:

```
@Data
@Entity
@Table(name = "berserk_cards")
public class BerserkCard {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    private String set;
    private String name;
    private Integer cost;

    @ElementCollection
    @CollectionTable(name = "berserk_card_elements", joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "card_id"))
    @Column(name = "element")
    private Set<String> elements = new HashSet<>();

    private String type;
    private String subtype;
    private Integer attack;
    private Integer health;
    private String rarity;
    private String text;
    private String painter;
    private Integer number;
}
```

It's ok, that page in url start has value = 1, and in logs = 0 because i have configured one-indexed-parameters: true.

Calling `http://.../api/cards?page=1&size=12`

```
2023-05-15T10:06:51.411+03:00  INFO 21056 --- [nio-9999-exec-1] r.b.c.i.h.s.BerserkHeroesCardServiceImpl : Accept pageable. Page 0, size 12
Hibernate: 
    select
        b1_0.id,
        b1_0.attack,
        b1_0.cost,
        e1_0.card_id,
        e1_0.element,
        b1_0.health,
        b1_0.name,
        b1_0.number,
        b1_0.painter,
        b1_0.rarity,
        b1_0.set,
        b1_0.subtype,
        b1_0.text,
        b1_0.type 
    from
        berserk_cards b1_0 
    left join
        berserk_card_elements e1_0 
            on b1_0.id=e1_0.card_id offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(b1_0.id) 
    from
        berserk_cards b1_0
2023-05-15T10:06:51.472+03:00  INFO 21056 --- [nio-9999-exec-1] r.b.c.i.h.s.BerserkHeroesCardServiceImpl : Found 2726 elements, total pages: 228
```

Calling `http://.../api/cards?page=2&size=12`

```
2023-05-15T10:06:53.277+03:00  INFO 21056 --- [nio-9999-exec-5] r.b.c.i.h.s.BerserkHeroesCardServiceImpl : Accept pageable. Page 1, size 12
Hibernate: 
    select
        b1_0.id,
        b1_0.attack,
        b1_0.cost,
        e1_0.card_id,
        e1_0.element,
        b1_0.health,
        b1_0.name,
        b1_0.number,
        b1_0.painter,
        b1_0.rarity,
        b1_0.set,
        b1_0.subtype,
        b1_0.text,
        b1_0.type 
    from
        berserk_cards b1_0 
    left join
        berserk_card_elements e1_0 
            on b1_0.id=e1_0.card_id offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only
2023-05-15T10:06:53.300+03:00  INFO 21056 --- [nio-9999-exec-5] r.b.c.i.h.s.BerserkHeroesCardServiceImpl : Found 23 elements, total pages: 2
```

Calling `http://.../api/cards?page=3&size=12`

```
2023-05-15T10:06:54.272+03:00  INFO 21056 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] r.b.c.i.h.s.BerserkHeroesCardServiceImpl : Accept pageable. Page 2, size 12
Hibernate: 
    select
        b1_0.id,
        b1_0.attack,
        b1_0.cost,
        e1_0.card_id,
        e1_0.element,
        b1_0.health,
        b1_0.name,
        b1_0.number,
        b1_0.painter,
        b1_0.rarity,
        b1_0.set,
        b1_0.subtype,
        b1_0.text,
        b1_0.type 
    from
        berserk_cards b1_0 
    left join
        berserk_card_elements e1_0 
            on b1_0.id=e1_0.card_id offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only
2023-05-15T10:06:54.299+03:00  INFO 21056 --- [nio-9999-exec-2] r.b.c.i.h.s.BerserkHeroesCardServiceImpl : Found 35 elements, total pages: 3
```

Calling `http://.../api/cards?page=4&size=12`

```
2023-05-15T10:06:55.521+03:00  INFO 21056 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] r.b.c.i.h.s.BerserkHeroesCardServiceImpl : Accept pageable. Page 3, size 12
Hibernate: 
    select
        b1_0.id,
        b1_0.attack,
        b1_0.cost,
        e1_0.card_id,
        e1_0.element,
        b1_0.health,
        b1_0.name,
        b1_0.number,
        b1_0.painter,
        b1_0.rarity,
        b1_0.set,
        b1_0.subtype,
        b1_0.text,
        b1_0.type 
    from
        berserk_cards b1_0 
    left join
        berserk_card_elements e1_0 
            on b1_0.id=e1_0.card_id offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(b1_0.id) 
    from
        berserk_cards b1_0
2023-05-15T10:06:55.561+03:00  INFO 21056 --- [nio-9999-exec-9] r.b.c.i.h.s.BerserkHeroesCardServiceImpl : Found 2726 elements, total pages: 228
```

and now i commented entity graph annotation

```
public interface BerserkCardRepo extends JpaRepository<BerserkCard, Long>, JpaSpecificationExecutor<BerserkCard> {

    @Override
    //@EntityGraph(attributePaths = {"elements"})
    Page<BerserkCard> findAll(@Nullable Specification<BerserkCard> spec, Pageable pageable);

}
```

Calling `http://.../api/cards?page=1&size=12`

```
2023-05-15T10:14:26.704+03:00  INFO 4036 --- [nio-9999-exec-4] r.b.c.i.h.s.BerserkHeroesCardServiceImpl : Accept pageable. Page 0, size 12
Hibernate: 
    select
        b1_0.id,
        b1_0.attack,
        b1_0.cost,
        b1_0.health,
        b1_0.name,
        b1_0.number,
        b1_0.painter,
        b1_0.rarity,
        b1_0.set,
        b1_0.subtype,
        b1_0.text,
        b1_0.type 
    from
        berserk_cards b1_0 offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(b1_0.id) 
    from
        berserk_cards b1_0
2023-05-15T10:14:26.742+03:00  INFO 4036 --- [nio-9999-exec-4] r.b.c.i.h.s.BerserkHeroesCardServiceImpl : Found 2726 elements, total pages: 228
```

Calling `http://.../api/cards?page=2&size=12`

```
2023-05-15T10:15:47.211+03:00  INFO 4036 --- [nio-9999-exec-3] r.b.c.i.h.s.BerserkHeroesCardServiceImpl : Accept pageable. Page 1, size 12
Hibernate: 
    select
        b1_0.id,
        b1_0.attack,
        b1_0.cost,
        b1_0.health,
        b1_0.name,
        b1_0.number,
        b1_0.painter,
        b1_0.rarity,
        b1_0.set,
        b1_0.subtype,
        b1_0.text,
        b1_0.type 
    from
        berserk_cards b1_0 offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(b1_0.id) 
    from
        berserk_cards b1_0
2023-05-15T10:15:47.250+03:00  INFO 4036 --- [nio-9999-exec-3] r.b.c.i.h.s.BerserkHeroesCardServiceImpl : Found 2726 elements, total pages: 228
```

Calling `http://.../api/cards?page=3&size=12`(the same for all other pages)

```
2023-05-15T10:17:03.992+03:00  INFO 4036 --- [io-9999-exec-10] r.b.c.i.h.s.BerserkHeroesCardServiceImpl : Accept pageable. Page 2, size 12
Hibernate: 
    select
        b1_0.id,
        b1_0.attack,
        b1_0.cost,
        b1_0.health,
        b1_0.name,
        b1_0.number,
        b1_0.painter,
        b1_0.rarity,
        b1_0.set,
        b1_0.subtype,
        b1_0.text,
        b1_0.type 
    from
        berserk_cards b1_0 offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only
Hibernate: 
    select
        count(b1_0.id) 
    from
        berserk_cards b1_0
2023-05-15T10:17:04.029+03:00  INFO 4036 --- [io-9999-exec-10] r.b.c.i.h.s.BerserkHeroesCardServiceImpl : Found 2726 elements, total pages: 228
```

As You can see, the differ in logs between wrong response and correct response is count query, which is not generated in incorrect response case.

Any have idea why is this happening?

Comment: Run your service in your IDE and step through the code as it executes to find out where the problem is.

Comment: I don't thing the UPD2 is ok. But let say you moved to Spring 3, java 17. using JpaRepository and you override findAll assume from JpaRepository that extend Paging. I hope you can test and show us the query and input of those call (You can . If it's happen, we got new bug to report on github. but you know what, I saw you are using mapping from BerserkCard to Model. We need it also

Comment: @NamNguyễn i tested different cases and added logs(logging response and request) in UPD3 of my post. Mapper no matter in this cases because repository return wrong result.
 Today i will trying to find reason inside jpa.

Comment: @Bohemian it looks i need to debug Hibernated libraries rather than my code, bcs flow in my code very simple. I think it may be hibernate or jpa bug and i really want  to know what is it

Comment: `LEFT JOIN` is causing the issue in your case.

Comment: @Antoniossss for page 1 and 4 also uses left join which return correct result

Comment: But that depends on the actual results - in your case presence or absence of  matchigg `elements`

Comment: What  you want, is to be able to limit/offset entity agregate, what you actually get is limt and offset of raw SLQ result set - this is quite common issue tbh. You can try using `@OneToMany` instead `@ElementCollection` with eager fetching instead of entity graph. Maybe in such case framework will correctly do the aggregation including proper count.

Comment: @Antoniossss 
Count  does not depend on `elements` because there are no joins in count query.
Also i what to understand, why 2 and 3 magic numbers?) for page 1 and 4...up to end... all ok, generates correct sql-s and returns correct results. Why for other pages hibernate generate count query, bur for page 2 and 3 not

Comment: Spring must have an issue with counting as it seems to think there are 1 less result for those pages then there should be, so is assuming this is the last page possible and so doesn't need to count to check how many are actually there. If those pages really have 12 results back, this is a Spring problem, not JPA or hibernate; the page size says there are 12 results returned, but give you a total count of 23 and 35 respectively which doesn't add up. If debugging, you should just go into spring Pageable handling, not into Hibernate itself.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem in eager collection `elements`.
If we see at sql in logs

```
Hibernate: 
    select
        b1_0.id,
        b1_0.attack,
        b1_0.cost,
        e1_0.card_id,
        e1_0.element,
        b1_0.health,
        b1_0.name,
        b1_0.number,
        b1_0.painter,
        b1_0.rarity,
        b1_0.set,
        b1_0.subtype,
        b1_0.text,
        b1_0.type 
    from
        berserk_cards b1_0 
    left join
        berserk_card_elements e1_0 
            on b1_0.id=e1_0.card_id offset ? rows fetch first ? rows only
```

We found that we skip ? rows and fetch ? rows. If there are two or more elements card has, we will found less unique entities in result set.

For example, in resultSet we have one card with two elements, and other with 1 elements. It means in resultSet we have 11 unique entities.

When spring parse resultSet to entities it found, that there are 11 entities it found meanwhile page size is 12. Spring saw that founded count of entities less than page size and it thinks that it's last page and don't call count query.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution to this problem.
Inside your specification class add: `query.distinct(true)`
And the count should now be correct.